# Return value from Angular function

Tags: angular, function, frontend

I am trying to make the connection to the backend in my application but I want to show a snackbar with the response I receive, but when I call the endpoint in charge of the action I can't get a response if it was correct or not, from the back if I get it and in the endpoint if I have the response but in my function where I call it I don't get it.

I have the function as follows and it is called by a button

**button function**

```
sendData(data:any, endPoint:any){
console.log(this.dataService.postForm(data,endPoint))
** I want to get the response here, but i got "undefined"
```

}

**Endpoint:**

```
postForm(dataPost:any, endPointValue:any){
    this.http.post<any>(`${this.BASE_URL}${endPointValue}/`, dataPost).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.router.navigate(['main']);
    }, err => {
        alert("404")
        this.router.navigate(['main']);
    });
}
```

**This is something that i want to do**

```
postForm(dataPost:any, endPointValue:any){
    this.http.post<any>(`${this.BASE_URL}${endPointValue}/`, dataPost).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        this.router.navigate(['main']); *This is not working too
        return response ** I want to catch this response
    }, err => {
        alert("404")
        this.router.navigate(['main']); *This is working
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad practice to return a Subscription from a Service (just like storing an endpoint in a component).

I guess this variant can work for you:

Service:

```
postForm(postDTO: any): Observable<any> {
  this.http.post<any>(`${this.BASE_URL}/your_endpoint_path`, postDTO)
}
```

Component:

```
sendData(data: any) {
  this.dataService.postForm(data).pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(console.log),
    catchError(err => alert(err.message))
  )
  .subscribe(_ => this.router.navigate(['main']))
}
```

Also don't forget to unsubscribe from every subscription when you don't need them anymore, to prevent memory leaks. In this case you need only 1 emission, so I added here "*take(1)*" pipe.

Comment: Thanks i tried your solution and it works, thank you so much :D

Comment: I'm happy to know it ;D

Answer (score 0):

```
postForm(dataPost:any, endPointValue:any){
this.http.post<any>(`${this.BASE_URL}${endPointValue}/`,    dataPost).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    this.router.navigate(['main']).then(()=>{
      return response;
     });
    
}, err => {
    alert("404")
    this.router.navigate(['main']);
});
```

}

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but i have another issue, the router.navigate is not working too, and i can't catch the return

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).